# How to read a file containing '\0' characters?

Tags: c++, c, buffer, fopen

I wrote a simple program to read a TXT file. The problem is the file contains some '\0' characters. Here's a sample :

[image]

And here's the solution I've found to solve my problem :

```
FILE *pInput = fopen("Encoded.txt", "rb");

    fseek(pInput, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(pInput);
    fseek(pInput, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *buffer = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        buffer[i] = fgetc(pInput);
```

I would like to replace the following code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        buffer[i] = fgetc(pInput);
```

By just a simple function call. Is there a function which can do this job ?
I tried with fread, fgets but they stop to read at the first '\0' character.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: `fread` does not stop at the first `0`. What makes you think it does? Do you have an example which demonstrates that it does?

Comment: What he said (since you fopen()ed with "rb" not "r"), and you probably want to do "new char[size+1]" and then after one big fread() do "buffer[size]='\0'" so it's NUL-terminated at the very end.

Comment: Doesn't look like a TXT file to me. Also note that any function that works with strings will stop processing your buffer at the first `'\0'`, even if you have read them all correctly.

Comment: Even fgetc() should read zero's. Are you sure it's not your further processing that fails due to the buffer containing NUL characters - e.g. using `printf("%s", buffer)` or for example `strcpy` or `strcat`?

Comment: @Inspired Ah, good point, so probably he did the fread() but then did something like strlen() and decided fread() didn't really read it all in. But it did.

Comment: If you use `std::string` (properly) then 0 is just another character and is handled just fine.

Comment: You're using a C++ tag so I'm assuming you accept C++ answers, correct?

Comment: Sorry, fread does not stop a the first '\0' effectively. I just wrote a printf call after that and of course printf stop to the first '\0'. But the buffer is correctly filled. Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread` is fine for reading arbitrary binary; it returns the number of elements read, which is a value you should *store* and use in all dealings with your buffer. (Read some documentation on `fread` to find out how it works.)

(On the other hand, with `fgets` you won't be able to find out how many characters were read because a pointer to a [assumedly null-terminated] C-string is all you get out of it.)

You need to ensure that your *handling* of your resultant buffer is zero-safe. That means no `strlen` or the like, which are all designed to work on ASCII input (more or less).

Comment: If this is not strlen() or printf(%s..) etc, I'll eat one of my chat-hats.

Comment: @MartinJames: If you can find it!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) and removing the plumbering that you'll find in the link:

```
  // Open the file with the pointer at the end
  ifstream file("example.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate); 

  // Get the file size
  streampos size = file.tellg();

  // Allocate a block
  char* memblock = new char [size];

  // We were at the end go to the begining
  file.seekg 0, ios::beg);

  // Read the whole file
  file.read(memblock, size);
```

Et voilà !